# Hibernate: hbm2ddl property values, create-drop always drops schema, even without explicit SessionFactory close?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm new to hibernate (just started last week), and I'm developing a medical records system.
I am using Hibernate 4.3, with MySQL, and I currently have my hbm2ddl.auto property set to create-drop, although I was using update before.

My problem is, even though I only have one declaration of

```
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = Connect.getSessionFactory();
```

and reuse this sessionFactory variable again when I'm making many inserts, it always drops by schema.
However, the hibernate documentation states that create-drop should only drop the schema when an
explicit call is made to sessionFactory.close();

```
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.SQLQuery;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

public class ConcreteMedicalDAO implements MedicalDAO
{
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = Connect.getSessionFactory(); 

    public void createDoctor(Doctor d)
    {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(d);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }

    public void retrieveDoctor(String firstName, String lastName)
    {
        String hql = "Select * from Doctor where firstName = :firstName and lastName = :lastName";

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        session.beginTransaction();
        SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(hql).addEntity(Doctor.class);
        query.setParameter("firstName", firstName);
        query.setParameter("lastName", lastName);
        List<Doctor> doctors = query.list();

        for(Doctor d: doctors)
        {
            System.out.println("Address: " + d.getAddress());
            System.out.println("Birthdate: " + d.getBirthDate());
            System.out.println("Degree: " + d.getDegree());
            System.out.println("First name: " + d.getFirstName());
            System.out.println("Gender: " + d.getGender());
            System.out.println("Last name: " + d.getLastName());
            System.out.println("Specialty: " + d.getSpecialty());
            System.out.println();
        }

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I haven't called sessionFactory.close(), and yet, my database is still wiped out every time. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Here are all of my classes that I am using in the application.

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="doctor")
@AttributeOverrides({
@AttributeOverride(name="firstname", column=@Column(name="firstName")),
@AttributeOverride(name="lastname", column=@Column(name="lastName")),
})
public class Doctor extends Person
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int dId;

    @Column(name="firstName")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="lastName")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="specialty")
    private String specialty;

    @Column(name="degree")
    private String degree;

    @Column(name="gender")
    private String gender;

    @Column(name="Address")
    private String address;

    @Column(name="birthDate")
    private String birthDate;

    @Column(name = "userName", unique = true)
    private String userName;

    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;

    public Doctor()
    {
    }

    public Doctor(String firstName, String lastName)
    {
        super(firstName, lastName);
    }

    public Doctor(String firstName, String lastName, String gender, String address, String birthDate, String specialty, String degree)
    {
        super(firstName, lastName);
        this.gender = gender;
        this.address = address;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
        this.specialty = specialty;
        this.degree = degree;
    }

    public int getdId()
    {
        return dId;
    }

    public void setdId(int dId)
    {
        this.dId = dId;
    }

    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName()
    {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName)
    {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getGender()
    {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender)
    {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getAddress()
    {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address)
    {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getBirthDate()
    {
        return birthDate;
    }

    public void setBirthDate(String birthDate)
    {
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    public String getSpecialty()
    {
        return specialty;
    }

    public void setSpecialty(String specialty)
    {
        this.specialty = specialty;
    }

    public String getDegree()
    {
        return degree;
    }

    public void setDegree(String degree)
    {
        this.degree = degree;
    }

    public String getUserName()
    {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName)
    {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword()
    {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password)
    {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Next, here's my hibernate.cfg.xml file

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

 <hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MedicalSystem</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">root</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop the existing tables and create new one -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>

        <!-- Mention here all the model classes along with their package name -->

        <mapping class="CS157B.Doctor"/>
        <mapping class="CS157B.Patient"/>
        <mapping class="CS157B.MedicalRecord"/>
        <mapping class="CS157B.Specialty"/>
        <mapping class="CS157B.Administrator"/>
        <mapping class="CS157B.Staff"/>

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Here's my patient class

```
  import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="Patient")
@AttributeOverrides({
@AttributeOverride(name="firstname", column=@Column(name="firstName")),
@AttributeOverride(name="lastname", column=@Column(name="lastName")),
})
public class Patient extends Person
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="pid")
    private int pid;

    @Column(name="firstName")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="lastName")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="gender")
    private String gender;

    @Column(name="birthDate")
    private String birthDate;

    @Column(name="address")
    private String address;

    @Column(name="seniorCitizen")
    private boolean seniorCitizen;

    @Column(name = "userName", unique = true)
    private String userName;

    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;

    @ManyToOne()
    private Doctor doctor;

    public Patient()
    {
    }

    public Patient(String firstName, String lastName)
    {
        super(firstName, lastName);
    }

    public Patient(String firstName, String lastName, String gender, String address, String birthDate, boolean seniorCitizen)
    {
        super(firstName, lastName);
        this.gender = gender;
        this.address = address;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
        this.seniorCitizen = seniorCitizen;
    }

    public int getPid()
    {
        return pid;
    }

    public void setPid(int pid)
    {
        this.pid = pid;
    }

    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName()
    {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName)
    {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getGender()
    {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender)
    {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getBirthDate()
    {
        return birthDate;
    }

    public void setBirthDate(String birthDate)
    {
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    public String getAddress()
    {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address)
    {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public Doctor getDoctor()
    {
        return doctor;
    }

    public void setDoctor(Doctor doctor)
    {
        this.doctor = doctor;   
    }

    public boolean isSeniorCitizen()
    {
        return seniorCitizen;
    }

    public void setSeniorCitizen(boolean seniorCitizen)
    {
        this.seniorCitizen = seniorCitizen;
    }

    public String getUserName()
    {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName)
    {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword()
    {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password)
    {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Finally, here's my Connect class:

```
   import org.hibernate.*;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

public class Connect
{
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

    private static SessionFactory configureSessionFactory()
    {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory()
    {
        return configureSessionFactory();
    }
}
```

I know this is kind of long, but this my first post to Stack Overflow.

Comment: What do you mean by everytime? Everytime you run the Application (Then it is the correct behaviour) or Everytime you call createDoctor/retrieveDoctor methods?

Comment: I agree with shazin, if you restart your app , your tables are deleted and replaced with new ones.

Comment: I do restart the application, but that's because I'm currently developing basic CRUD utilities for the Doctor class. I just want the data I create through my application to persist in the database, and not be removed every time I restart the application.

Comment: If you don't want the tables to be dropped and recreated then you shouldn't use hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto to create-drop. And try using an SQL Script to load initial data to the tables instead of relying on data being created while running the application.

Comment: Sure, I'll try that, but I prefer having persistent data, and automated mapping to tables done by Hibernate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it for update your schema

update

instead of

create-drop

In the case of using hbm2ddl.auto is create-drop, every time it will drop your schema and create new one when you deploy your project. But in the case of hbm2ddl.auto, whenever you will deploy your project and insurt data in to your database, it will update your database instead off drop and create.

Comment: Yeah, update works, but I don't want to use it in production, thanks for your help.